# Group an JavaScript objects in array in specific order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
var tracks = [
  { id: 0, vibe: "downtempo" },
  { id: 1, vibe: "midtempo"  },
  { id: 2, vibe: "uptempo"  },
  { id: 3, vibe: "uptempo"  },
  { id: 4, vibe: "midtempo" },
  { id: 5, vibe: "downtempo"  },
  { id: 6, vibe: "midtempo" },
  { id: 7, vibe: "midtempo"  },
  { id: 8, vibe: "uptempo"  },
  { id: 9, vibe: "uptempo"  },
  ... 
  { id: 100, vibe: "midtempo"  },
];
```

What is the best way to sort this array to group objects by 'vibe' and get such sequence:

```
 { id: 0, vibe: "downtempo" },
  { id: 5, vibe: "downtempo" },
  { id: 15, vibe: "downtempo"  },
  { id: 1, vibe: "midtempo"  },
  { id: 4, vibe: "midtempo" },
  { id: 6, vibe: "midtempo" },
  { id: 2, vibe: "uptempo"  },
  { id: 3, vibe: "uptempo"  },
  { id: 8, vibe: "uptempo"  },
  { id: 12, vibe: "downtempo" },
  { id: 25, vibe: "downtempo" },
  { id: 45, vibe: "downtempo"  },
  ...
  { id: 100, vibe: "uptempo"  },
```

Thank you!

Comment: Its not a dublicate. My question is about how to group by 3 and put it in order

Comment: do you like it to be sorted by `vibe`?

Comment: group and sort, i need such sequence:
downtempo, downtempo, downtempo, midtempo, midtempo, midtempo, uptempo, uptempo, uptempo, downtempo, downtempo, downtempo, midtempo, midtempo, midtempo, uptempo, uptempo, uptempo

Comment: you are right, the wanted order is different. but what have you tried? please supply a greater data set for testing. you may have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: does my answer work for you?

Comment: yes, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) by using a temporary object with a hashtable for the same group array. Take from it the length of the used array as group for sorting.

The sorting happens with the `group`, `key` and `index`.

The result is mapped with index of the sorted temporary array.

```js
var array = [{ id: 0, vibe: 'downtempo' }, { id: 1, vibe: 'midtempo' }, { id: 2, vibe: 'uptempo' }, { id: 3, vibe: 'uptempo' }, { id: 4, vibe: 'midtempo' }, { id: 5, vibe: 'downtempo' }, { id: 6, vibe: 'midtempo' }, { id: 7, vibe: 'midtempo' }, { id: 8, vibe: 'uptempo' }, { id: 9, vibe: 'uptempo' }, { id: 10, vibe: 'midtempo' }, { id: 15, vibe: 'downtempo' }, { id: 12, vibe: 'downtempo' }, { id: 25, vibe: 'downtempo' }, { id: 45, vibe: 'downtempo' }],
    size = 3,
    order = { downtempo: 1, midtempo: 2, uptempo: 3 },
    groups = Object.create(null),
    result = array
        .map(({ vibe, key = order[vibe] }, index) => ({
            group: Math.floor(((groups[key] = groups[key] || []).push(key) - 1) / size),
            key,
            index
         }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.group - b.group || a.key - b.key || a.index - b.index)
        .map(({ index }) => array[index]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```